# Twilio cannot check available numbers

Tags: curl, twilio

I'm using the code directly from Twilio's [webpage](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/availablephonenumber-tollfree-resource) for getting available phone numbers and I'm getting an error back about a json not being found.

The command is:

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/'$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'/AvailablePhoneNumbers/US/TollFree.json?PageSize=20' -u $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
```

The response is:

```
{
  "code": 20404, 
  "message": "The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/SK*******************************/AvailablePhoneNumbers/US/TollFree.json was not found", 
  "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404", 
  "status": 404
}
```

Looking into the error `20404` [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/20404) seems like the issue is mostly just it's not formatted properly (bad SID, incorrect path, etc.). I don't believe any of these issues pertain to my problem, but I don't know what to do to fix this either. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong or what I have setup incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I see you've answered your own question here, but I wanted to add more detail.

When making API requests to the Twilio API you can authenticate using either the Account SID and Auth Token that is available on your [Twilio console dashboard](https://console.twilio.com/?frameUrl=/console) or using an [API Key and Secret that you can generate in the console](https://console.twilio.com/us1/account/keys-credentials/api-keys?frameUrl=/console/project/api-keys).

But, it has to be noted that the API Key is not the Account SID. In a request to the URL `https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/'$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'/AvailablePhoneNumbers/US/TollFree.json?PageSize=20` requires the actual Twilio Account SID, even if you are using an API Key and Secret to authenticate the request.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that I was using the incorrect authentication information. I assumed I was to make an api key associated with my account and use that SID and authentication token. That was incorrect and I was supposed to just use the account SID and account authentication token.

So if you run into this problem, make sure you're not using the api key information.